# Makefile with Django collectstatic to gzip assets; Makefile variable depends on target

Tags: django, makefile, gnu-make, bower

I am creating a Makefile to automate the "build" process of my Django application. One step is to gzip all static CSS and JS files. Here is my Makefile thus far:

```
CSS_FILES = $(shell find static -type f -name "*.css")
CSS_GZ_FILES = $(CSS_FILES:.css=.css.gz)
JS_FILES = $(shell find static -type f -name "*.js")
JS_GZ_FILES = $(JS_FILES:.js=.js.gz)

all: static $(CSS_GZ_FILES) $(JS_GZ_FILES)

bower_components: bower.json
    bower --config.interactive=false install

static: bower_components
    python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

%.gz: %
    gzip -9 -c -f $< > $@

clean:
    rm -rf bower_components static
```

If you aren't familiar with Django, the static target dumps a bunch of JS and CSS (and more) files into the `static` directory.

The problem, the list of CSS and JS files can't be determined until the `static` target runs. So the first time running `make`, no files are gzipped. What I want is the list of CSS, JS files to be re-evaluated after `collectstatic` runs.

I thought about working around this by running `collectstatic` before I run make, but `collectstatic` itself depends on a different make rule.

If it helps, this Makefile will only run with GNU Make.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is with auto-generated makefiles.  Something like this should work OK; add near the top of your makefile (before you use `$(CSS_FILES)` or `$(JS_FILES)` for anything):

```
-include static-output.mk
```

then add near the bottom of your makefile (or at least, not as the first target):

```
static-output.mk: bower_components
        python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
        @( echo 'CSS_FILES := $$(shell find static -type f -name "*.css")'; \
           echo 'JS_FILES := $$(shell find static -type f -name "*.js")'; ) \
         > $@
```

and remove the settings of CSS_FILES and JS_FILES from your makefile and remove the "static" stuff.  I don't really understand what "bower_components" is for or where it comes from so I can't advise on that.

Comment: The bower_components directory contains third party JavaScript packages (such as jQuery). Bower pulls in the JavaScript libraries then collectstatic will copy those JavaScript files into the static directory. The static target can't run until the bower_components are available.

Comment: You really don't want to have a make target depend on a directory.  Make bases its decisions on modification times, and the rules for when a directory's modification times are updated are very different from files.  The question is, is it useful to run those two commands separately?  If both commands need to be run whenever bower.json changes, why not have both in the same recipe?

Comment: The reason I created two recipes is because they create two different directories. One recipe creates the bower_components directory, while the other creates the static directory. I figured the recipe's are separate because separate output is created. But then that gets back to your comment about not using directories as targets.

Comment: Right.  You don't need to tie rules to directories.  The question you have to ask is, is there any advantage in running just one of them?  If it's possible to have the bower command run, then change something that does NOT require the bower command to re-run but DOES require the collectstatic command to re-run, then splitting them makes sense because you save work in some cases.  But if every time bower.json runs you have to run both, and if every time one fails you have to modify bower.json to fix it, there's no reason to have two separate rules.